# Parsing CloudKit Error (CKError)

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckerror

I'm using CloudKit and I'm checking if a specific zone was already created.

For this example, let's say that a zone isn't set, so CloudKit retrieves me a `CKError`.

This `CKError` has a property called `partialErrorsByItemID` which is of type `[AnyHashable : Error]?`

Here's the code:

```
fileprivate func checkIfZonesWereCreated() {
    let privateDB = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
    let op = CKFetchRecordZonesOperation(recordZoneIDs: [zoneID1, zoneID2])
    op.fetchRecordZonesCompletionBlock = { (dict, err) in
        if let err = err as? CKError, let _err = err.partialErrorsByItemID {                    
            print(_err) 
            /* prints 
            [AnyHashable(<CKRecordZoneID: 0x60800003cba0; ownerName=__defaultOwner__, zoneName=TestZone>): <CKError 0x60400005a760: "Zone Not Found" (26/2036); server message = "Zone 'TestZone' does not exist"; uuid = ...-2DF4E13F81E2; container ID = "iCloud.com.someContainer">]
            */

            // If I iterate through the dictionary
            _err.forEach({ (k, v) in
                print("key:", k) // prints: key: <CKRecordZoneID: 0x60800002d9e0; ownerName=__defaultOwner__, zoneName=TestZone>
                print("value:", v) // prints: value: <CKError 0x60400005a760: "Zone Not Found" (26/2036); server message = "Zone 'TestZone' does not exist"; uuid = ...-2DF4E13F81E2; container ID = "iCloud.com.someContainer

            })

            return
        }
        print("dict:", dict)
    }
    privateDB.add(op)
}
```

How do I parse this error? I need to access the `zoneName` ?

Comment: Update your question with a bit more code showing your call to CloudKit and your current error handling.

Comment: @rmaddy I tried to cast the `key` as `Dictionary<String, Any>` but it doesn't work. If it did I could then access the `zoneName` subkey then get the value

Comment: You could try casting `_err` to `[AnyHashable : Any]` then use the `zoneID` as a key to get the `CKError` value (casting it to `CKError`) and finally access `CKError.code` (zone not found has a CKError.code raw value of 26).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key in `_err` is a `CKRecordZoneID`. Once you have that, use the `zoneName` property to get the zone name.

I would write your code as follows:

```
fileprivate func checkIfZonesWereCreated() {
    let privateDB = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
    let op = CKFetchRecordZonesOperation(recordZoneIDs: [zoneID1, zoneID2])
    op.fetchRecordZonesCompletionBlock = { (dict, err) in
        if let err = err as? CKError {
            switch err {
            case CKError.partialFailure:
                if let _err = err.partialErrorsByItemID {
                    for key in _err.keys {
                        if let zone = key as? CKRecordZoneID {
                            let name = zone.zoneName
                            print("Missing zone: \(name)")
                        }
                    }

                    return
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        print("dict:", dict)
    }
    privateDB.add(op)
}
```

Comment: This is so good! If you only knew how many times you've "saved my life".
Thank you so much.

Comment: Great answer. Also provides scope for handling other cases of `CKError`.